# Check if list of 'partial' strings is in list of full strings

Tags: python, string, algorithm, list, python-3.x

Sorry for the title, really couldn't think of an easy way to explain this situation.

So if I have one list of strings, such as:

```
list_1 = [ "cat", "rat", "mat" ]
```

How can I check that all of those strings are in another list that may have 'fluff' around it (by that I mean, instead of say "cat" it may have "cat_mittens" which would be fine, but "car_mittens" isn't).

So for example:

```
list_A = [ "cat", "car", "cab" ]
list_B = [ "cat", "rat", "bat", "mat" ]
list_C = [ "cat_mittens", "rat", "mat" ]
```

Here, if I did the analysis on `list_A` I'd want False returned, for `list_B` I'd want True returned, and likewise for `list_C` I'd want True returned (as it contains all 3 strings of list A, even though "cat" has extra bits around it (what I referred to as fluff).

My current approach is:

```
list_1 = [ "cat", "rat", "mat" ]
list_C = [ "cat_mittens", "rat", "mat" ]

temp_list = [False,] * 3

count = 0
for temp_1 in list_1:
  temp_list[ count ] = any( temp_1 in temp_2 for temp_2 in list_C )
  count += 1

result = all( temp_list )
```

There's an added complication that, in my actual code, all the strings in list C need to contain an additional string (e.g. all would need say "_filetype") but that's less of an issue (I do this within the final "all" statement).

My method works, but in my opinion it's quite messy (not least because I call things temp, making it potentially unclear what is what. I guess I could rename them to something else, but off the top of my head I can't think of anything meaningful to name them) and I'm not sure how efficient it really is.

Is there another way of achieving this?

Sorry if I haven't explained this well! If anything needs clarification, please just let me know.

Comment: what do you want to return for `["ratcatmat"]`?

Comment: your question might a good fit for [codereview.SE](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/6143)

Comment: I wasn't aware of codereview.SE, but will certainly post this type of question there in the future so thanks for letting me know about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def check_all(substrings, strings):
    """Check all *substrings* are in *strings*."""
    return all(any(substr in s for s in strings) for substr in substrings)
```

Example:

```
>>> list_1 = [ "cat", "rat", "mat" ]
>>> list_A = [ "cat", "car", "cab" ]
>>> list_B = [ "cat", "rat", "bat", "mat" ]
>>> list_C = [ "cat_mittens", "rat", "mat" ]
>>> check_all(list_1, list_A)
False
>>> check_all(list_1, list_B)
True
>>> check_all(list_1, list_C)
True
>>> check_all(list_1, ["ratcatmat"])
True
>>> check_all(["bc", "ab"], ["abc"])
True
```

Comment: That's quite a nice way of doing it, and certainly having it has a function might make it easier to clarify what's going on (i.e. make it more general rather than bogged down in the application).

Answer (score 2):

you dont have to save the result in a list, you can do

```
result = True
for s in list_1:
    result &= any(s in test_string for test_string in list_C)
print result
```

this can be made more efficient (but less clean) if you do:

```
def check(list_1, list_2):
    for s in list_1:
        if not any(s in test_string for test_string in list_C):
            return False
    return True
```

EDIT:

the &= syntax simply performs a AND operation and on both variables

so this

```
x &= y
```

is equivalent to this

```
x = x & y
```

with means x will be True only if both x AND y are True

so if `y=True` and `x=True` then the result will be True, but if for example `y=False` then the result will be False

Comment: Oh, I haven't come across the syntax "&=" before. Any chance you could briefly explain how it works? I tried searching for it, but as it's just symbols, it's not that easy aha

Comment: @Steve: type `help('&=')`

Comment: Thank you! (Have to say, feel a little embarrassed that I've been using Python for over a year and didn't realise it had an inbuilt help function/document)

Comment: i will add it to the answer for future viewers

Comment: Quite a nice method, with the &= causing it to only be able to change from True to False and not back.

Comment: Just wanted to add, I accepted J.F. Sebastian's answer as it's both clear what it's doing and (or perhaps because) it's a function. However, this solution is also much better than what I originally had.

Comment: FWIW, it's more efficient to use the boolean `and` rather than the bitwise `&`, eg `result = result and any(s...` because `and` short-circuits, which means it won't evaluate its second operand if the first is False. However, using `all()` on a generator is neater (as in J.F. Sebastian's answer), since it also short-circuits, so it breaks the loop as soon as a False value is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for item in list_1:
    for item2 in list_C:
        if item in item2:
            count += 1
            break
res = 'True' if count==len(list_1) else 'False'
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in python3. This should print desired result.

```
list_1 = [ "cat", "rat", "mat" ]
list_2 = [ "cat_mittens", "rat", "mat" ]

for i in list_2:
    for j in list_1:
         if j in i:
            print(i)
```

I hope this is what you want to do.